# Make a subset of dtaframe according to column value python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have generated dataframe frame and created a csv file now I want to make a subset of dataframe in which it checks the value of column `"dst"` (uptill 0) and then take value of `Image` column.
My current dataframe is:

```
     Image   Maxval   locx  locy  dst
0    1.jpg    0.99      22    47    0
1    7.jpg    0.46      27    65    18.68
2    11.jpg   0.32      18    29    18.43
8    18.jpg   0.25      7     38    17.49
10   1.jpg    0.99      40    71    0
11   18.jpg   0.56      27    71    17.68
13   7.jpg    0.42      93    17    19.43
19   11.jpg   0.35      70    39    17.49
```

The image are sorted according to maxval so i don't want to change the order of images.I want my dataframe to be:

```
   Image    Image
  1.jpg     1.jpg
  7.jpg     18.jpg
  11.jpg    7.jpg
  18.jpg    11.jpg
```

Comment: Is first value in `dst` column always `0` ? If not, whats happens with rows before first `0`?

Comment: if the column maxval value is 0.99 then the first value of dst is always 0

Comment: So always is `maxval` value `0.99` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If first value in `dst` column is always `0` compare value `0` and create new column value by `cumsum` fo cumulative sum and groups by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), last use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['c'] = df['dst'].eq(0).cumsum()
df['g'] = df.groupby('c').cumcount()
df1=df.pivot('g','c','Image').add_prefix('Image_').rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print (df1)
  Image_1 Image_2
0   1.jpg   1.jpg
1   7.jpg  18.jpg
2  11.jpg   7.jpg
3  18.jpg  11.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

1. Get the groups of images based on the `dst` column

```
groups = df.groupby(df.dst.eq(0).cumsum())['Image']
```

2. Concat every groups after resetting the index for each of them:

```
pd.concat([group.rename('Image_' + str(indx)).reset_index(drop=True) for indx, group in groups], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Image_1 Image_2
0   1.jpg   1.jpg
1   7.jpg  18.jpg
2  11.jpg   7.jpg
3  18.jpg  11.jpg
```

As you can see I also renamed the columns in the concat function by renaming the series, but that is not necessary if you really want to have the name "image" for every groups.

Comment: `but that is not necessary if you really want to have the name "image" for every groups.` - I think duplicated column names is really bad idea, because then problem with selecting. So the best is use like your answer.